# How to stop, restart, pause, resume via NSSM or cmd?

Tags: cmd, windows-services, nssm

So NSSM has the command start to start the service:

```
nssm start my-service
```

However looking at the documentation I can't seem to find any other commands. It does state how it will shutdown the service but the actually command doesn't seem to exist.

So how does one stop, restart, pause, resume a service via NSSM and if that is not possible how does one do this via the `cmd`?

Comment: Please delete your question and answer. The fact that you failed to read fully the information does not help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I totally missed this page: https://nssm.cc/commands

```
nssm start <servicename>
nssm stop <servicename>
nssm restart <servicename>
nssm pause <servicename>
nssm continue <servicename>
```